# 1 item could not be synced. See iTunes for more information

Tags: data-synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iTunes Sync: X items could not be synced. See iTunes for more information](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29569/itunes-sync-x-items-could-not-be-synced-see-itunes-for-more-information)

I am trying to sync some MP3s to my iPhone 4S and keep getting the above message. I have seen some replies to this kind of query but only in relation to photos or videos. What more information am I supposed to be looking for?

Comment: Have you looked over some answers here on the topic ? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29569/itunes-sync-x-items-could-not-be-synced-see-itunes-for-more-information

Comment: Or here... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37612/where-do-i-look-in-itunes-to-find-sync-errors

Answer (score 0):

iTunes displays an alert when it is unable to sync specific audio or video content to your iPhone, iPad, or iPod. iTunes offers a checkbox to not show the alert again. If you select this checkbox, the alert will no longer appear during sync.

Connect your device to your PC or Mac.
Wait until your device has appeared on the left side of the iTunes window under Devices.
Right-click (PC) or Control-click (Mac) the icon for your device.
From the shortcut menu, choose Reset Warnings.